# Best way to count this?

Tags: counting

I'm trying to use the Count function for this purpose, but it's not working how I'd like it to. Does anybody know a simple way to do this counting?

I would like to be counting the number of "p"s in expressions like

```
p[1,2][1]^2 p[3,4][3]
```

or

```
p[3,3][1]
```

I would like the count to return 2 on the first one (even though one of the p's has a squared term), and 1 on the second.

edit: I realized for the purpose of counting I can remove the "square" so the first expression would just look like

```
p[1,2][1]p[3,4][3]
```

if that makes it any easier.

Comment: Do they always come in the form `p[a, b][t]`?

Comment: What should it return of `f[p]`?

Comment: @belisariusisforth: Seems like you're violating your `Principle of don't-ask-questions-to-expand-the-scope-of-the-question`. :)

Comment: @march yes they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to turn it into a string and count the number of occurences of `p` in the string:

```
StringCount[ToString[p[1, 2][1]^2 p[3, 4][3]], "p"]
```

Comment: I had just figured this out and was about to answer my own question with that! Thanks though.

Comment: Ahem: `p["p"]`... :D (To be fair to you, the OP didn't mention that they only wanted to count symbols although that's how I interpreted the question)

Answer (score 12):

This works:

```
Count[p[1, 2][1]^2 p[3, 4][3], _p, ∞, Heads -> True]
```

Answer (score 4):

"And Now for Something Completely Different"...

```
expr = p[1, 2][1]^2 p[3, 4][3];

Module[{n = 0}, expr /. p :> n++; n]

(*  2  *)
```

No claim to be "best"

Comment: Cute, though: +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
Length[Position[p[1, 2][1]^2 p[3, 4][3], p]]
```